# POC - Start Service on boot without an Activity - Android 4+

Tags: android, android-service

This question may seem a trivial but I've been struggling with it.

I'm trying to **start a service on boot** and everything works fine if I start it at least once from the `mainActivity` (launch activity), something like:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
...
<activity
android:name="com.example.mainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.example.bootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.example.someService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
...
```

**bootReceiver.java**

```
...
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.someService.class));
...
```

**mainActivity.java**

```
...
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.someService.class));
...
```

With the above code I'm able to run the service after every boot without any problems.

---

As a **POC**, I'm trying to **start a service without any activity**, or at least without the `mainActivity`, just by declaring the service on the `AndroidManifest.xml` or by creating new activity (invisible?) that is launched at the same time as the default launcher activity. 
As far a I know, this isn't possible on android 3+ (4+?) due to security reasons.

Is there any way to achieve this ?
Can I start 2 activities **from the** `AndroiManifest.xml` when the user launches the app?

I'm sorry if my question isn't 100% clear, I've tried to explain it the best I could, if you cannot understand it, please leave a comment bellow. Tks.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for your reply.  What I'm trying to achieve is to start the service **without the user run an Activity once after installation**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far a I know, this isn't possible on android 3+ (4+?) due to security reasons.

Android 3.1, actually, to help prevent drive-by malware.

> Is there any way to achieve this ?

Something has to use an explicit `Intent` to invoke some form of IPC on one of your components, to move the app out of the so-called "stopped state" that is preventing you from receiving the broadcast. So, something needs to either:

- start one of your activities via an explicit `Intent`, or
- start one of your services via an explicit `Intent`, or
- send a broadcast to one of your receivers via an explicit `Intent`

(I don't know if trying to connect to a `ContentProvider` will work, though arguably it should)

The key is the explicit `Intent`. That's why invoking an activity from a home screen launcher works, because the `Intent` used to start your activity will be an explicit one.

However, in the absence of such an activity, you would need to find something else that would use an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your components. Certain specialized services (e.g., an input method) probably get invoked with an explicit `Intent` if and when the user activates that app's capability via the system Settings app. If you're a plugin for some other app, that other app might use an explicit `Intent` to work with one of your components. You can ask the user to install the Android SDK, learn how to use the command line, and invoke an `adb shell am` command to start one of your components. And that's about all I can think of off the top of my head. None are exactly general purpose solutions.

> or by creating new activity (invisible?) that is launched at the same time as the default launcher activity

I have no idea what you think that would achieve. If the user starts up your launcher activity, you're already out of the stopped state and will receive broadcasts as normal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As a POC, I **cannot add the intent that starts the service** to the `mainActivity`, or change any code inside it,  but I'm allowed to create a new activity that launches the service. That's why I asked if it was possible to launch 2 activities from the `AndroidManifest.xml` at launch time. Is it possible?

Comment: @PedroLobito: No, it is not possible for a single launcher icon to be tied to two separate activities. Each activity with the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` gets its own launcher icon; that icon launches that one and only activity. Moreover, I fail to see how this has anything to do with your stated objective ("start the service without the user run an Activity once after installation").

Comment: I apologize if my question is confuse. Since I cannot change the code inside the  `mainActivity` in order to add the explicit `Intent`, I thought  I could create a new activity to start the service that would be launched at the same time as the default launcher activity (`mainActivity`). Thanks to you, I realized this isn't possible. I'll mark your question as correct. Thank you for your time.